# Voiceover support in ObjC++

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, iphone, voiceover

I have an ObjC++ code for iOS. (It has, UI elements comes from c++ code). I would like to support VoiceOver. Could somebodyshow me some examples about the VO interfaces? I have found some documentation about VO (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/VoiceOverAccessibility.html) but I didn't found the developer documentation about the programming of VO module. I do not really know how to start this.

I have read this article: [Can I support VoiceOver in my Cocos2D-iPhone Game?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899285/can-i-support-voiceover-in-my-cocos2d-iphone-game) but it is still not clear for me.

1. How can I send VoiceOver if it is a button or a switch, or anything
   else?
2. How can VoiceOver highlight the button on the UI?
3. How can it read the labels of the widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Accessibility Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html) should get you started. Note that all the interfaces for this are in Objective-C, so if necessary, you will need to wrap your c++ objects to be made accessible in Objective-C (but you might already be doing so) and then implement accessibility on the wrapper.